# Post FHIR bundle model to Aws healthlake datastore using java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, hapi-fhir

Am doing a POC to test whether we can post FHIR Bundle model resourceType to Aws Healthlake datastore. Looking at the documentation it sounded like there is a way to ingest to datastore via Aws S3 as a source but am looking to, a direct ingest to datastore. Is that possible ?

Below is the link for documentation that tell how to ingest from S3.

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/healthlake/HealthLakeClient.html#startFHIRImportJob(software.amazon.awssdk.services.healthlake.model.StartFhirImportJobRequest)

Help is appreciated!